# Выбрать правильный тип библиотеки

Tags: c#, uwp

Пишу клиент-серверное приложение. Сервер - консольное приложение, клиент - UWP. Какой тип библиотеки выбрать, чтобы ее можно было подключить туда и туда? Я провел пару тестов. Мне удалось подключить к клиенту и серверу библиотеки типа: "Библиотека классов (Переносимая, для ios, andriod and windows)", "Библиотека классов (Переносимая, для windows 8)". Мне не подходит эти да типа. Другие типы не удается подключить сразу к 2 приложениям. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая библиотека PortableClassLibrary для всех платформ одновременно. Можно в ней сделать необходимые классы и ее подключать можно куда угодно

Comment: Где, что, как? Конкретно такого там нету.

Comment: В студии файл- создать - проект - выбираешь среди темплейтов Portable Class Library, выбираешь галочки, какие платформы должны поддерживать код, и получается библиотека классов, которую можно подключать в выбранные типы проектов